# How to pick the value of the day before?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to get help with a query that returns the value of the day before?

let's say I have a table of 2 columns one of the dates and the other of revenue (number).

I would like to get for each day in the table the revenue of the day before.

I tried to run this query but it only returns to me the value of the same day and not the day before

```
SELECT 
date(u.creation_date),
COUNT(CASE WHEN date(u.creation_date) = date_sub(date(u.creation_date), INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "yestarday"
FROM user u
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

I expect the output of 
date, revenue , revenue of the day before

```
09/04 , 1, 0
09/05 , 2, 1
09/06 , 1, 2
09/07 , 5, 1
09/08 , 4, 5
```

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have mysql 8 or above you need to either use a sub query or a join. AND I don't know why you are using count to sum revenue.

```
create table t
(dt date, revenue int);
insert into t values
('2019-01-01',1),
('2019-01-01',1),
('2019-01-02',1);

select dt, sum(revenue) today,
         (select sum(revenue) from t t1 where t1.dt = t.dt - 1) yesterday
from t
group by dt;

select t.dt, sum(t.revenue) today,
         y.revenue as yesterday 
from t
left join (select dt,sum(revenue) revenue from t group by dt)  y on y.dt = t.dt -1
group by t.dt;

+------------+-------+-----------+
| dt         | today | yesterday |
+------------+-------+-----------+
| 2019-01-01 |     2 |      NULL |
| 2019-01-02 |     1 |         2 |
+------------+-------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: 1) include such information in the question 2) use date function https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date to Extract the date part of the date

Comment: select date(t.creation_date), COUNT(t.id) today,
         y.revenue as yesterday 
from user t
left join (select creation_date,COUNT(id) revenue from user t group by creation_date)  y on y.creation_date = t.creation_date -1
group by 1,3;

*Plase ignore the COUNT() it's ok for me.

When running this query I'm getting all NULL values on yesterday

Comment: Thats the first time id has been mentioned - it would be better if you published sample data as text rather than me guessing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no gaps in the table, you can do:

```
SELECT DATE(u.creation_date) + INTERVAL 1 DAY,
       COUNT(*) as yesterday,
       SUM(u.revenue) as yesterday_revenue
FROM user u
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```